# Adding Height to Image for Subtitle

Tags: c#, image, image-manipulation

i want to add an additonal height to an Image to give it a subtitle.
I do not want to "compres" or resize my original image.
I want to keep it's size and add +40 px to its height on bottom and add a text like [this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WDke.jpg)

The red part is the original image.
The blue part is my addition.

I tried this code but my text appears "outside" the image i think.

```
Image image = Image.FromFile("D:\\my_sample_image.jpg");
// Create graphics from image
Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image);
// Create font
Font font = new Font("Times New Roman", 42.0f);
// Create text position
PointF point = new PointF(150, image.Height+40);
// Draw text
graphics.DrawString("Watermark", font, Brushes.Red, point);
// Save image
image.Save("D:\\my_sample_output.jpg");
MessageBox.Show("FINISHED");
// Open generated image file in default image viewer installed in Windows
Process.Start("D:\\my_sample_output.jpg");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make a new Bitmap, create a Graphics out of it, then draw the old image with room for text at the bottom.

```
Bitmap image = new Bitmap("path/resource");
Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height + 40);
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
{
      // Draw base image
      Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height); 
      g.DrawImageUnscaledAndClipped(image, rect);
      //Fill undrawn area
      g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 0, image.Height, newImage.Width, 40);
      // Create font
      Font font = new Font("Times New Roman", 22.0f);
      // Create text position (play with positioning)
      PointF point = new PointF(0, image.Height);
      // Draw text
      g.DrawString("Watermark", font, Brushes.Red, point);
 }
```

Comment: my output image still looks same like the input image.

Comment: I apologize, try using DrawImageUnscaled() rather than DrawImage.

Comment: Sorry it doesnt work. There does not change anything. i do not even see the text. i changed first line to:  Image image = Image.FromFile("D:\\my_sample_image.jpg");

Comment: Sorry, just tested, I made edits. this should work. The text was just positioned incorrectly.

Comment: Works! but the image is *scaled* up

Comment: My actual code: http://pastie.org/private/j3mkogkyahaglxcimwujq But quality is not as fine as the original image.

Comment: Interesting, That didn't happen on my end. 
How is it scaled up? From what size to what size?

Comment: The actual size is correct. but the image seems like it is "zoomed"

Comment: g.DrawImageUnscaledAndClipped did it !

Comment: Correct code: Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height);
                g.DrawImageUnscaledAndClipped(image, rec);

Comment: Great, I updated the code for people looking for this in the future. Good luck on the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0):

```c#
public Image addSubtitleToImage(string path, int height, string title)
{
    Bitmap image = new Bitmap(path);
    Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height + height);
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
    {
        g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Black), new Rectangle(0, 0,   newImage.Width, newImage.Height));
        g.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height));

        Font font = new Font("Tahoma", 30.0f);
        g.DrawString(title, font, Brushes.White, new PointF(image.Width/2 , image.Height+));

    }
    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: Pls explain your code ab bit -> no code only answers